# How to prove this integer inequality?

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

Given $\alpha _{n}= 1+\frac{1}{1!}+...+\frac{1}{n!} ,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

How would I prove the following statement?

$\alpha _{n}< 3$

Comment: Hint: $\alpha_n<e=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k!}<3$

Answer (score 1):

$2! \geq 2, 3! > 2^{2}, ...$ Can you finish?

[Use the fact that $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {2^{k}}=1$].